# C# NEST ElasticSearch Default_Search analyzer

Tags: c#, search, elasticsearch, default, nest

In short I want to be able to have an analyzer that is only applied for searching. Sorting should go by the default analyzer.

By adding this code I can successfully get the searching working as intended. When I search for "be" I find stuffs with "Bé".

```
        var an = new CustomAnalyzer();
        an.Tokenizer = "keyword";
        an.Filter = new List<string>();
        an.Filter.Add("standard");
        an.Filter.Add("lowercase");
        an.Filter.Add("ascii_folding");

        return await CreateIndexAsync(c => c
            .Index(_index)
            .Analysis(a => a.Analyzers(a1 => a1.Add("default", an)))
            .Analysis(a => a.TokenFilters(tf => tf.Add("ascii_folding", new AsciiFoldingTokenFilter { PreserveOriginal = true })))
        );
```

This results in my sortings also becomes ascii folded. 
A
Å 
B etc etc.

Reading here it looks like I should be able to apply my analyzer to only search instead.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-analyzers.html#default-analyzers

"and the default_search can be used to configure a default analyzer that will be used just when searching"

If I understood this correctly I should be able to apply my analyser to only search by changing this row.

```
            .Analysis(a => a.Analyzers(a1 => a1.Add("default_search", an)))
```

This breaks the analyser completely. Search will be going by the default and be will not hit Bé. Any ideas what Im doing wrong here?

Here is my request

```
Request: {
  "from": 0,
  "size": 70,
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "Name",
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "_all": {
              "value": "*be*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {}
}
```

It shouldn't be any problem that I use Wildcard search in _all ?

And here is a request with sorting. The problem is that my results here get sorted by the ascii folded value ( if i use default analyzer )

```
    Request: {
  "from": 0,
  "size": 70,
  "sort": [
    {
      "Name": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "Name"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you´re always performing the search on the _all field you can put up a different analyzer just for that.

Create two analyzers, one standard and one with ascii_folding.

```
var allAnalyzer = new CustomAnalyzer();
allAnalyzer.Tokenizer = "keyword";
allAnalyzer.Filter.Add("customasciifolding");

var defAnalyzer= new CustomAnalyzer();
defAnalyzer.Tokenizer = "keyword";
defAnalyzer.Filter = new List<string>();
defAnalyzer.Filter.Add("standard");
```

Create the index with your analyzers.

```
return await CreateIndexAsync(c => c
            .Index(_index)
            .Analysis(a => a
                .Analyzers(a1 => a1
                    .Add("default", defAnalyzer)
                    .Add("customAll",allAnalyzer)
                )
                .TokenFilters(tf => tf.Add("customasciifolding", new AsciiFoldingTokenFilter { PreserveOriginal = true })
                )
            )
        );
```

Then when you map set it up like the following

```
await _elasticClient.MapAsync<MyClass>(m => m
            .MapFromAttributes()
            .AllField(af => af.Analyzer("customAll"))
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you need to apply [sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html), because right now you sorting is based on [_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html). 
So your query is filtering by wildcard, and then depends by score (where match is found and how often) results are sorted

```
.Analysis(a => a.Analyzers(a1 => a1.Add("default_search", an)))
```

You can do like that so you will set it as default analyzer with ascii filter

PS. After question update.
You should use [multifield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html) so you should have one analyzed field one not analyzed. Search on analyzed, sort on not analyzed

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I will look into it.
Edit: uhm. It still doesnt explain why I can't use "default_search".. regardless if sort or not I only want my ascii applied to the searching :/

Comment: you actually can but you need to patch it :) It should be with ascii, otherwise you will not be able to search properly. Without ascii A ÅÆ are totaly different letters

Comment: I have tried to add the "default_search" analyser. According to the documentation it sounds like its exactly what I want to do. But if I do that it just ignores to fold.

Comment: @Evelie I have updated answer. You must use multifield

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-analyzers.html#default-analyzers

Here it looks like I can apply an analyzer to only search? Do I really have to use multifield for that?
I want my index to still go by the deafault untouched. the only thing I want is to add an analyzer for the search, and the search only. 

Thanks for taking your time helping me btw.

Comment: Now when you sort you sort on analyzed field long to explain but simple "text like that" in analyzed index could be "text", "like", "that" so when you do multiple fields you have actually like a two fields 1 untouched and second analyzed